# How to Build a Shopping Cart with Oracle Apex Collections

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I Need help to build a shopping cart in Oracle Apex where a user can select multiple orders and in the right side, the cart is displayed with the ordered items summary.

Until the order completion, nothing can be inserted in the database.
When the Order is completed, the ordered items are stored in the database.

[image]

Comment: Seems you have a good idea about what to do. You've got the interface already. What's not working? What did you try? You know you have to work with collections, what is it you don't understand about them? Have you checked the documentation on collections? What's the problem?

Comment: You're in a stateless environment, you will need to insert into the database. But that's what APEX_COLLECTIONS are for.

Comment: @Tom How to restrict duplicate entries in apex_collections as i don't want to store data in database until the order taken is completed?

Comment: Counter not worked,, please fix this problem..                               declare COUNT_N number;
begin
  select count(*) into COUNT_N
  from wwv_flow_collections
  where collection_name='order_add'
  and n001 =  :P27_M_ID;
 
  IF COUNT_N=0 THEN
    apex_collection.add_member(
    p_collection_name => 'order_add',
    p_c001            => :P27_ITEM_NAME,
    p_n001            => :P27_M_ID,
    p_n002            => :P27_QUANTITY,
    p_n003            => :P27_PRICE,
    p_generate_md5    => 'YES' );  
  end if;
end;